# Building full calendar for week schedule planning

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to build a planner for the schedule for 1 week on Rails.

Right now I am looking into the jquery plug-in [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

It offers a weekly view with different time slots and draggable events, the functionalities which I needed. However, it does planning for a full time range when I only need it for one week.

I am new to jQuery, so I would appreciate it if someone could give me guidance on whether it is a good idea to use this plug in for my application.
If it is, how should I go about doing it and if it isn't are there any other better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on this plugin to add new tab along with Month , Week and day. In this case, you can remove the Month and Day tabs, so it works only for the current week.

Then you change the source, where it would show the week which you want.

For Example if you look at the calendar initialization, it would look like

```
header: {
            left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }
```

if u see the attribute `right`, you can see month, agendaWeek, agendaDay (all are keywords). try removing the month and agendaDay, you will see only the agendaWeek. 
fullCalendar also support other types of week displays. Open the plugin or read the documentation. If you are lucky, it may be available already, or it is not a big deal to edit the plugin. after all its javascript

Comment: Thanks for answering. I meant for it to be  where I can arrange the schedule for days in the week. So in that case I should remove year and month then?

Comment: I got the gist of it. Thanks for your help.